Incrementally rename all text files without 'duplicate' errors
Given the files 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt etc., I want to identify the existing number, and rename the file incrementing that number by 1.
The problem is the various errors I get. Duplicates, files that cant be found, only some get renames correct etc..
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "extension=%%~xf"
    
    REM Check if the filename is a number and increment it
    if "!filename!" neq "" (
        set /a newNumber=!filename! + 1
        set "newFilename=!newNumber!!extension!"
        
        REM Check if the new filename already exists
        if exist "!newFilename!" (
            echo Duplicate name: "!newFilename!" already exists.
        ) else (
            ren "%%f" "!newFilename!"
        )
    )
)
echo
pause
endlocal

I expect this:

0.txt → 1.txt
1.txt → 2.txt
2.txt → 3.txt
3.txt → 4.txt
4.txt → 5.txt
200.txt → 201.txt


for %%f in (*.txt) do ( gets files in ascending order. Hence, renaming 0.txt => 1.txt will fail if there exists 1.txt. Get files in descending order as follows: for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /O:-N *.txt') do ( … HTH

As @JosefZ said, you should be working backwards in descending order.

Alright. I have done it.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Loop through existing .xhtml files in reverse order
for /L %%i in (478, -1, 0) do (
    if exist %%i.xhtml (
        set /a newnum=%%i + 1

        rem Attempt to rename the file
        ren %%i.xhtml !newnum!.xhtml
    )
)

endlocal

Make sure to indicate the highest number name in the code. Mine was 478.

Your code is suboptimal because: 1-It requires the highest file number, and 2-It process all numbers even if some files does not exists... Try: for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /O:-N *.xhtml') do set "next=%%~Nf+1" & ren "%%f" "!next!.xhtml" as JosefZ suggested
